# IoT Hub - how to register for lifecycle events - disconnect and connect?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

- This is still not solved. Can someone please check my comments below? Anyone?

How can I subscribe for when an IoT device connects and disconnects to the IoT Hub?

I checked out these couple of links - and that might solve the issue - but I was hoping it was more simple than having to set up an entire Cosmos Database (I don't have one yet) and an Event Grid:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-how-to-order-connection-state-events

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid

I already have an Event Hub set up and message routing from my IoT Hub to get notifications when a device twin changes and that works great. Can't I just expand on that somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Event subscriptions on your IoT Hub supports many different endpoints. If you already have an Event Hub set up you can use that in combination with an event subscription. To do this from the portal, you go to your hub and to the Events blade. Add a new subscription that listens to 'Device Connected' and 'Device Disconnected' events and use the Endpoint Type 'Event Hubs'. Then simply select your existing hub. Screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just like you've set up message routing for "Device Twin Change Events", you should be able to route "Device Lifecycle Events" to the same (or different) Event Hub.

Comment: I just did that. However, after lots of testing. I still don't get notifications for "Device Lifecycle Events", only "Device Twin Change Events". Is there something missing in my configuration?

Comment: ...could it be that when I turn off the device, which makes its "connectionState" property in its device twin go to "Disconnected", a lifecycle event will NOT be triggered? I want to be notified when devices disconnect.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: kartben, do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @JonTh - Not sure if you ever solved this, the Connect/Disconnect you were after are from the "Device Connection State Events"  - Device Lifecycle Events are created/deleted.